# Is there a "prettier" way to extract the [[PromiseResult]] than this?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am new and still learning how to use firestore. So I managed to `console.log()` my 1 document and all its fields. However, I haven't found a good looking way to extract that data from firestore. So far, I managed to make everything work with this:

```
async function getProducts(specificProduct) {
  let data = await getDoc(doc(db, "MyProductList", specificProduct));

  return data.data();
}
let price = getProducts("someProduct");
let price1 = [];

function getDesc() {
  price
    .then((e) => {
      price1.push(e.Description);
    })
    .then(() => console.log(price1[0]));
}
```

But, this doesn't look right to me. It feels ugly, though I'm not sure if it's just me. So I was wondering if maybe there was a better way to write this.

Comment: depending on how you want to use the data, you could just directly log the `e.Description` rather than pushing it into an array, then logging that array element? not sure what you mean by prettier however

Comment: "doesn't look right" and "feels ugly" are really subjective. Can you clarify what would make it look right and beautiful for you?

Comment: Maybe try looking at tutorials?

Comment: You can use `await price` instead of `.then()`. This is the modern "syntactic sugar" that makes working with promises easier.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I apologize, my wording was vague.  What I meant was that it was kind of redundant. Using `.then` multiple times just extends the code unnecessarily and  I know there exists a more compact way of doing it but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use another `async` function with `await` instead of `then`:

```
async function getDesc() {
    const price = await getProducts("someProduct");
    const price1 = [];
    price1.push(price.Description);
    console.log(price1[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I have been searching for this solution for a while now!